# Zentyal- Can I run zentyal as a virtual?

Tags: networking, zentyal

I am very new to the networking industry and I'm not sure whether this is a stupid question or not but..

Can I run Zentyal on a virtual machine?

Please also explain why.

::I would like to practice and learn Zentyal so if I could run this as a virtual server and allow it to serve my physical pc and maybe a virtual machine to it.::

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can!** I installed Zentyal inside VMware at my company.

Comment: Yes, it is. OP was asking about running Zentyal on VM. And the answer is yes because why not.

Comment: Now it is an answer....  **;-)**